# Why boto3 dose not recognize my AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID in Django on EC2?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I was connecting the S3 to Django on EC2.
I confirmed that it works on the my computer (window),
but when I uploaded it to `AWS EC2 Ubuntu` and ran it,
I saw the following message.
when i ran `python manage.py` commands

```
File "/home/ubuntu/django/e/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 821, in create_client aws_secret_access_key)) **botocore.exceptions.PartialCredentialsError: Partial credentials found in explicit, missing: aws_secret_access_key**
```

But I think I set it up correctly. in my `settings.py`

```
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3.me-south-1.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME= config('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_kEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_kEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
```

I tried

1. Give IAM permission on EC2
2. Delete EC2 retry
3. set env var via  `export`
4. throw away virtualenv and try
5. install awscli and configure it
6. s3 bucket policy configure
7. tried to write it inline because it might not be able to refer to the .env file, but it gave me same message.

I struggled with this problem all day today. When it comes to AWS Config, I think I've tried everything I can. If you have any guesses about the cause of this problem, please give me a hint.

And I only think boto3 looks up keys in a peculiar way on EC2

## AWS role setting worked correctly :) And i notice that I should set setting.py `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_kEY` and  `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` `None` when i am using EC2 with IAM role

Comment: Did the IAM role have an `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` with `sts:AssumeRole` enabled for `ec2.amazonaws.com`

Comment: @Exelian  .. i gave it AmazonS3FullAccess and AmazonEC2FullAccess Roles

Comment: Those are the permission, but not the trusted entities. Click on the role in the IAM console and select the "Trust relationships" tab. It should mention EC2.amazonaws.com as "The identity provider"

Comment: @Exelian !Oh Ok . Thank you very much. I'll try it tomorrow. I was so tired today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real way to resolve this issue is by using EC2 InstanceProfiles linked to an IAM role STS permissions granted to EC2.

It's a bad practice to store your AWS credentials on an instance and you should definitely avoid it.

Create an IAM role with the appropriate permissions and attach it to the instance by selecting "Modify IAM role" when right clicking on it in the console.

Comment: Just to clarify, there should be no reason whatsoever to have you `access_key_id` and `secret_key` on your instance. None

Comment: I've been attaching IAM, giving s3 permission. Well, after attaching IAM, I didn't delete the key in settings.py ... maybe that is problem... and thanks i will check about InstanceProfiles

Comment: Make sure IAM role has EC2 as trusted entity, otherwise AWS won't pass on the permissions to the instance